# Can the simple present be used for temporal actions?

Tags: grammar, present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple, progressive-aspect

As far as I know, the simple present is used to state facts, how things exist or behave. However, I have seen the following sentence:

- I *walk* to class during the week.

Regarding that the present continuous is used to describe actions happening temporarily, I wonder whether we should not use the **present continuous** in the sentence as follows:

- I *am walking* to class during the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I walk to class during the week.

This is a fact, not a temporal action.  "During the week" means each week, probably Monday to Friday (though local context might change this) It include this week, last week, next week, the first week in November, every week forwards and backwards in time.

So it isn't about a temporary action.

Note that you could truthfully say "I walk to class during the week" both on Wednesday and on Sunday. It remains permanently true.

However, if you say

> I'm walking to class this week.

It is limited to one week, so is temporary, and the present continuous should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, why is the definite article "the" used before "week" in such a situation?

Comment: I'm understanding that as a "generic the"  like "The tiger is the largest cat in the world"

Answer (score 1):

*During the week* simply marks ***when*** the action of *walking* is performed. It does not indicate whether the action is temporary or not.

> I ***walk*** to class during the week.

states that the person walks to class during the week ***every week***. This is a general statement that is true every week, so it is not a temporary action. If you say

> I ***am walking*** to class during the week.

the meaning is changed. The sentence now states that you are *temporarily* walking to class during the week and although a particular period is not expressed, it is implied (e.g. ***this year, this semester***, etc).

There would be a possibility to say

> I ***am walking*** to class ***(during) this week***.

to mean that this action lasts for one week only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, why is the definite article "the" used before "week" in such a situation?

Comment: To express a **typical** action. [This thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/571224/during-the-weeks-vs-on-the-weekends) might help you.